# Ever managed to fake the Autotune effect?

Tags: sound-effects

I'll describe [Autotune](http://www.antarestech.com/products/auto-tune-evo.shtml) as a pitch "discretiser", though I've been unsuccessful in my attempt to recreate a similar effect.

I want to create a bitstream effect from a water stream recording and I feel like it's the effect I need. First I tried Digi's [Lo-Fi](http://www.avid.com/US/products/D-Fi) but this produces an old-sounding modem-like effect. I've played around with compressors and expanders to make an aliased (square) envelope but I can't find anything for the pitch.

Have you ever created a bitstream sound effect this way? I think I read about this on this board but can't seem to find it... About the DIY Autotune, do you know of any trick to get it done?

Comment: When you say "bitstream effect," @Justin, do you mean a hard sound effect to reinforce data transmission or some other kind of technology-related visual?

Comment: @NoiseJockey It's exactly what I mean, when beeps go crazy. I'm trying to turn this water recording into a river of beeps.

Comment: http://freemusicsoftware.org/category/free-vst-effects-2/bit-crusher

Plug it through that.  Even SLIGHTLY downsampling things can have a huge effect.

Comment: And, by "that" I mean the bitcrusher -- first one in the stack.

Comment: It downloads a DLL, although I found some bitcrushers for mac as AU's or VST's... @Dave, are you familiar with Digi's Lo-Fi? are they not equivalent with bitcrushers? They all seem to do the same downsampling and wordlength reduction. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with any if Digi's stuff, unfortunately.  Much to my dismay, I don't even have an M-Powered version of ProTools.

Most bitcrushers do the same thing, though... I'm just big on free effects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're on PT... If you have any of the extra packs you should have gotten [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/), which will do a similar trick to AutoTune (draw in random pitches on the grid)... Also if you have Waves, try the [MondoMod](http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=240) - square wave, 100% mix, max Pitch and Amplitude values to start - adjust to taste.

Comment: I'm on Pro Tools indeed, and it seems like I'm hoping to do too much with the basic plugins... unfortunately I'm not looking to purchase anything but a pair of NT1-A's in the near future... I guess I'll just mouth my effects for now, the time for me to get recognized :D

Answer (score 2):

I made a folder full of data stream sounds and made most of them using granular processing - either with [GRM Freeze](http://www.grmtools.org/) (mess with the random pitch) or with Pluggo granular plugins... I tended to use sounds with some element of pitch/harmonics in them, but with the stream recording you should be able to get a burbling data stream if you play with the pitch & envelope of the granules...

Comment: @tim, thanks a lot. I'll definitely investigate granular processing!

Comment: So, for anyone interested, there is this SOS article on granular synthesis (http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/dec05/articles/granularworkshop.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Autotune has a very unique sound to it and it's become so recognizable that it will be hard to fake. One thing you could try is drawing a pitch envelope over the sound using [Pitch 'n Time](https://serato.com/pitchntime-pro).
Radical shifts in pitch may create a similar effect.

[image]
<sub>(source: [serato.com](http://serato.com/sharedimages/19/919/919.jpeg))</sub>

Secondly, if you are using Nuendo, I believe there is a function that allows you to draw real-time pitch envelopes over the track in the timeline. Any Nuendo users care to share more on this?

Answer (score 1):

You responded to my comment, "@NoiseJockey It's exactly what I mean, when beeps go crazy. I'm trying to turn this water recording into a river of beeps." Rad.

I can't recommend an Auto Tune clone, but have you tried the free AudioUnit plugin called [Buffer Override](http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/audiounits.html)? It can impart a vocoded sound to a sample that you can make clean or glitchy, and it can be fully automated, which can make the apparent pitch of the pseudo-vocoding change over time.

Comment: @NoiseJockey, thanks! now checking out this plugin!

Comment: @NoiseJockey, what do use Audio Units (AU's) with? I'm running Pro Tools, and the only piece of software I own that is able to use AU's is GarageBand. It doesn't work in 48k, which Im unhappy about. What do you use?

Comment: I use Logic Pro as my alternate DAW and BIAS Peak as my stereo editor. 

Answer (score 1):

It won't sound like Autotune, but if you're trying to

> "turn this water recording into a river
>   of beeps"

have a look at the mda 'Tracker' AU from http://mda.smartelectronix.com/ - it tracks pitches in a sound, and can resynthesize them or reinforce using EQ or ringmod.

Comment: Cheers, I'll take look!